# Card VS Box render Difference

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-cardview, android-compose-card

Is there an explanation for why this

```
Card(
        modifier =
        Modifier
            .background(
                brush = Brush.horizontalGradient(
                    colors = listOf(
                        OrgFarmTheme.colors.secondary,
                        OrgFarmTheme.colors.onSecondary
                    )
                )
            )
           .clip(RoundedCornerShape(10))
    ) {
...
}
```

renders [image: this],

while

```
Box(
        modifier =
        Modifier
            .background(
                brush = Brush.horizontalGradient(
                    colors = listOf(
                        OrgFarmTheme.colors.secondary,
                        OrgFarmTheme.colors.onSecondary
                    )
                )
            )
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(10))
    ) {
...
}
```

renders [image: this] ?

I have tried using the default `shape` parameter of the `Card`, but it renders the same.

Comment: Well the same is found true for Box VS Surface

Comment: The `Card` has a default `backgroundColor` defined by `MaterialTheme.colors.surface`

Comment: Implying it is impossible to apply a gradient to a Card?

Comment: For my specific use-case where I have to use a custom `Layout`requiring the index of each child within it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Card` background color is defined by the **`backgroundColor`** property and not by the `background` modifier. This property also has a default value = `MaterialTheme.colors.surface` which is applied by default to the `Card`.
It is the reason of the difference in your code.

If you want to achieve with the `Card` the same layout of the `Box` you have to use:

```
Card(
    modifier =
    Modifier
        .background(
            brush = Brush.horizontalGradient(
                colors = listOf(
                    MaterialTheme.colors.secondary,
                    MaterialTheme.colors.onSecondary
                )
            )
        )
        ,
    backgroundColor =  Transparent,
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(10),
    elevation = 0.dp //it is important to avoid borders
)
```

If you want a `Box` with elevation and a gradient as background you can use the **`shadow`** modifier:

```
Box(
    modifier =
    Modifier
        .shadow(12.dp,RoundedCornerShape(10),true)
        .background(
            brush = Brush.horizontalGradient(
                colors = listOf(
                    MaterialTheme.colors.secondary,
                    MaterialTheme.colors.onSecondary
                )
            )
        )
        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(10))
) {
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you sir. It did try to add the elevation = 0.dp, and it works exactly as intended (like a Box). However, my very purpose of using a Card was to elevate it upon focus, giving it a hovering effect. It is alright if the elevation = 0.dp, but upon increasing the value by a slightest bit, the effect starts to deteriorate.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve elevation with gradient? Are you editing this answer if there is one, or shall I start a new question?

Comment: @MARSK I've updated the answer with an example of box, with elevation and gradient.

Comment: Excellent solution sir. Thank you!